# Adding the annotation on map is leading to app crash [Titanium]

Tags: android, ios, titanium, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to add around 1000 annotation on the map. Here is my code snippet:

```
nsNearby.markersSetup = function() {
 var location = Alloy.Globals.playgroungLocationList.locations;
 var annotationData = [];
 for (var i = 0,
    len = Alloy.Globals.playgroungLocationList.locations.length; i < len; i++) {

    var mapAnnotation = nsNearby.mapModule.createAnnotation({
        latitude : location[i].latitude,
        longitude : location[i].longitude,
        title : location[i].name,
        subtitle : location[i].street
    });

    if (Titanium.Platform.osname === "android") {
        mapAnnotation.pincolor = nsNearby.mapModule.ANNOTATION_BLUE;
    } else {
        mapAnnotation.pincolor = nsNearby.mapModule.ANNOTATION_PURPLE;
    }

    nsNearby.mapView1.region = {
        latitude : location[i].latitude,
        longitude : location[i].longitude,
        latitudeDelta : 1,
        longitudeDelta : 1
    };
    annotationData.push(mapAnnotation);

  }
  nsNearby.mapView1.setAnnotations(annotationData);
};
```

In iOS, it is working fine, but in Android, the app is crashing while adding the annotation.

If I put some specific numbers of annotation, it works.

It might be because of the extra load while placing the annotations. But, is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you get in logcat ?

Comment: I didn't get any error. It just stops working and app crashes.